# Column chart shifts from tick

Tags: highcharts

In stockchart the chart's column name doesn't appear below the column.Please refer the image.
[image]

My code:

```
xAxis: {
   minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
   minRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
   type: 'datetime',
   tickInterval: 24 * 36e5
   }
```

In the image the blue columns are 7th,9th and 11th date but the labels are not displayed.

Comment: Have you disabled `xAxis.ordinal` option? I suggest to do so, unless you need that option. In case you need ordinal axis, then use `tickPositioner`.

Comment: Does xaxis.ordinal exist in current highstock version? I am unable to find it in the api docs in highcharts.com. I also applied ordinal:false to the chart but it is not effecting the chart.

Comment: Yes it exists in highstock, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal)

Comment: I have set oridnal to false. `ordinal: false` but the issue is not solved.